# windows7 class path changed

Tags: windows, classpath

I write `java` in command line, But Output is here:

[image]

But my jdk is here:

```
D:\Windows.old\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
```

What should do?

Can i set windows java class path to `D:\Windows.old\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11` Or not?

My windows is is `C` drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes,** you must set java class path to `D:\Windows.old\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11`

Otherwise Environment variable does not find jdk1.7

#### Step how to set Class Path Window 7

1. Open Control Panel and Select System and Security
2. Select System
3. Select Advanced System Settings (Left Side)
4. Pop up Window Select "Advanced" (Tab)
5. Select Environment Variables (bottom)
6. Select and Edit Path Environment variable (add with this `;D:\Windows.old\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11`) **Do not delete the path existent,**
7. Verify Java path by typing javac in command prompt

#### javac is not recognize:

Go to **Control Panel**. **Environment Variables** and **Insert** the address at the beginning of **var**. Path followed by semicolon. i.e `D:\Windows.old\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11;` . **Do not delete the path existent,** just click in and go to the left end and paste the line above. Do not try anything else, because you just need to link your code to "javac.exe" and you just need to locate it.

Try to execute
Close your command prompt and reopen it,and write the code for compile and execution.

Comment: I do that, But `javac` not recognized